# Why is redshift inefficient event for the simplest select queries?

Tags: performance, view, amazon-redshift

I have a few views in my Redshift database. There are a couple of users who perform simple select statements on these views. When a single select query is run, it executes quickly (typically a few seconds) but when multiple select queries(same simple select statement) are run at the same time, all the queries get queued on the Redshift side and take forever to retrieve the results. Not sure why the same query taking a few seconds get queued when triggered in parallel with other select queries.

I am curious to know how can this be resolved or if there is any workaround I need to consider.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons why this could be happening.  First off how many queries in parallel are we talking about?  10, 100, 1000?

The WLM configuration determines the parallelism that a cluster is set up to perform.  If the WLM has a queue with only one slot then only one query can run at a time.

Just because a query is simple doesn't mean it is easy.  If the tables are configured correctly or if a lot of data is being read (or spilled) a lot of system resources could be needed to perform the query.  When many such queries come along these resources get overloaded and things slow down.  You may need to evaluate your cluster / table configurations to address any issues.

I could keep guessing possibilities but the better approach would be to provide a query example, WLM configuration and some cluster performance metrics (console) to help narrow things down.